# what does below attribute(IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY) means?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using spring security. also i am new to spring security. what does below line indicates(). Please help me?

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/MyPath/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Security Anonymus authentication is a nice way to handle not autenticated users with the same concepts like authenticated once

> Note that there is no real conceptual difference between a user who is “anonymously authenticated” and an unauthenticated user.

@See [Spring Security Reference: Chapter 12 Anonymous Authentication](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/anonymous.html)

At least it mean that every url that match `/MyPath/**` can be accessed without restrictions.